# Delete all elements in a list except two o three

Tags: python, list

Assuming I have this list

```
 [['GA', 11], ['GO', 25], ['GE', 23], ['DA', 22], ['DE', 33], ['DU', 54], ['DD', 55], ['DF', 27]
```

Given this example of a short list compared to a list of 500 items, how could I remove all items from this list except for GA, GO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
l = [['GA', 11], ['GO', 25], ['GE', 23], ['DA', 22], ['DE', 33], ['DU', 54], ['DD', 55], ['DF', 27]] 
l = [item for item in l if item[0] in ['GA', 'GO']]
```

This is a list comprehension with condition. There are plenty of tutorials, it's very useful.

Comment: Thank you, I created this list after having a sequence of words like this:

TATCTATCGATATCTATCTATC

where TATC and GATA is a word, the problem is .. my code is counting all these words after separating them into a list. The problem is that there are 5 TATC and 1 GATA, and my code basically does this:

[['GATA', 5], ['TC', 1], ['TATC', 4]

I don't know if you can understand me, but how could I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

```
data = [['GA', 11], ['GO', 25], ['GE', 23], ['DA', 22], ['DE', 33], ['DU', 54], ['DD', 55], ['DF', 27]]

result = [x for x in data if x[0] == 'GA' or x[0] == 'GO']
```

**Output:**

```
[['GA', 11], ['GO', 25]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use sets for lookup

```
[i for i in [['GA', 11], ['GO', 25], ['GE', 23], ['DA', 22], ['DE', 33], ['DU', 54], ['DD', 55], ['DF', 27]] if i[0] in {'GA','GO'}]
```

Output

```
[['GA', 11], ['GO', 25]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
l2 = [e for e in l if e[0] in ('GA','GO')]
```

Or

```
l2 = []
for e in l:
  if e[0] in ('GA', 'GO'):
    l2.append(e)
```

Note also that you don't want to modify the list while iterating over it, create a new list (`l2`).